# Axis tranformation in ggplot - How do I change the scale on a specific interval?

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I've made a violin plot that looks like this:

[image: Violin plot of credit ratings]

As we can see most of the data lies near the region where the score is 0.90-0.95. What I wish is to focus on the interval 0.75 to 1.00 by changing the scale giving less space to ratings from 0 to 0.75.
Is there a way to do this?

This is the code I'm currently using to create the violin plot:

```
ggplot(data=Violin_plots, aes(x = Year, y = Score)) +
  geom_violin(aes(fill = Violin_plots$Year), trim = TRUE) +
  coord_flip()+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +   
  theme(legend.position = 'none') + 
  labs(y = "Rating score", 
       fill = "Rating year", 
       title = "Violin-plots of credit rating scores")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to transform the scale to focus more in the upper region (e.g. add `trans = "exp"` as an argument to the scale), a non linear scale is often hard to interpret appropriately.

For such use cases, I recommend `facet_zoom` from the ggforce package, which is pretty much built for this exact purpose (see vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/vignettes/Visual_Guide.html#contextual-zoom)).

I also switched from `geom_violin() + coord_flip()` to `geom_violinh` from the ggstance package, which extends ggplot2 by providing flipped versions of ggplot components. Example with simulated data below:

```
library(ggforce) # for facet_zoom
library(ggstance) # for flipped version of geom_violin

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = rating, y = year, fill = year)) +
  geom_violinh() + # no need to specify trim = TRUE as it's the default
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +   
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  facet_zoom(xlim = c(0.75, 0.98)) # specify zoom range here
```

[image: plot]

Sample data that simulates the characteristics of the data in the question:

```
df <- diamonds[, c("color", "price")]
df$rating <- (max(df$price) - df$price) / max(df$price)
df$year <- df$color
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second plot to zoom in on the original plot, without modifying the data, by using `ggplot2::coord_cartesian()`

```
ggplot(data=Violin_plots, aes(x=Year,y=Score*100)) + 
geom_violin(aes(fill=Violin_plots$Year),trim=TRUE) + 
coord_flip() + 
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.75, 1.00)) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues") +
theme(legend.position='none') +
labs(y="Rating score",fill="Rating year",title="Violin-plots of credit rating scores")
```